# SVG - list of global attributes and events?

Tags: javascript, php, html, svg, traits

In HTML, all elements share a set of global attributes, like `class`, `id`, the `data-` specification, a common set of Javascript events and a couple of things here and there.

But how about SVG? I'm trying to build a trait in PHP able to represent the very core of a SVG element (so I can build every SVG object with this core set of attributes and add the specific attributes for that object in its own declaration).

The [SVG section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute) in the Mozilla Developer Network has a full-blown page with lots of attributes, but the only core attributes, according to their documentation, are `id`, `xml:base`, `xml:lang`, `xml:space`

I see the `class` attribute is on the navigation links, but not referred in the attributes category section, which confuses me a lot.

Isn't the `class` attribute a global one like in HTML? And what about the Javascript events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class attribute is not global feFuncA doesn't have it for instance, nor does that element support javascript events. There are others.

Attributes are listed [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/attindex.html) in a list that shows which elements support them.

Comment: I see. I'll rewrite my trait according to that, then. Thank you very much for the information :)